# Is there a self-map of the disk with Jacobian everywhere greater than $1$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, geometric-measure-theory

It might be silly, but I am not sure how to approach this problem.

> Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be the **closed** unit disk. Does there exist a smooth map $f:D \to D$ such that $\det df >1$ everywhere?

I don't assume $f$ maps boundary to boundary.

The area formula implies that such a map cannot be injective.

I guess this is somewhat related to the question of existence of maps of non-zero degree between disks.

Comment: I think you can map the disk to a very oblong ellipse, and then wind this ellipse around the center of the disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In complex coordinates, the map $f: z \mapsto \frac{z+2}{3}$ sends the 
closed unit disk $D = \bar{B}(0,1)$ to $D' = \bar{B}(\frac23,\frac13)$, a disk of radius $\frac13$. The Jacobian of $f$ is constant and equals to $\frac1{3^2} = \frac19$.

In polar coordinates, the map $g: (r,\theta) \mapsto (r,10\theta)$ sends $D'$ to a subset of the annulus $A = \bar{B}(0,1) \setminus B(0,\frac13)$. Since $0 \not\in D'$, $g$ is a smooth map. The Jacobian of $g$ is another constant and equals to $10$.

If one compose $f$ with $g$, one obtain a smooth map $g\circ f :
D \to A$ with constant Jabocian $\frac{10}{9} > 1$.

Comment: Ultimately, this construction should be similar to the one of Christian Blatter. I understand this one better.

Answer (score 2):

Choose an $N\gg1$, and map $D$ to an ellipse $E\subset R:=[-2N,2N]\times\bigl[-{1\over N},{1\over N}\bigr]$ by putting
$$f_1:\quad (x,y)\mapsto \bigl( 2Nx,{1\over N}y\bigr)\ .$$
We have ${\rm det}(df_1)=2$. Now use a map $f_2$ with ${\rm det}(df_2)\approx1$ to wrap the long rectangle  $R$ essentially area preserving   around the annulus
$$A_\rho:=\bigl\{(x,y)\in D\bigm| \rho\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq1\bigr\}$$
with $\rho$ slighty smaller than $1-{2\over N}$.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please give some more details about your map $f_2$?  How exactly do you "wrap" this rectangle onto the annulus? I also don't see the role of choosing $\rho \sim 1-\frac{2}{N}$. Why this specific choice? How does it relate to the construction? Thanks.

Comment: @AsafShachar: Its essentially the same as what achille hui did.

Comment: Ah OK, thank you.