# Is there a mapping of the disk with Jacobian greater than 1 that respect the boundary?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-measure-theory

This is a follow-up of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3619972/is-there-a-self-map-of-the-disk-with-jacobian-everywhere-greater-than-1).

> Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be the closed unit disk. Does there exist a smooth map $f:D \to D$ such that $\det df >1$ everywhere and $f(\partial D) \subseteq \partial D$?

Does anything change if I require $f|_{\partial D}=\text{Id}_{\partial D}$?

If we do not impose boundary conditions, then the answer [is positive](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3620233/104576).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $D^n$ denote the closed $n$-dimensional unit disk. Let $f: (D^n,\partial D^n)\to (D^n,\partial D^n)$ be  a smooth map of pairs with $J_f(x)\ne 0$ for all $x\in D^n$. Then $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

To prove this, observe first that $f$ is a local homeomorphism. Then "double" $f$ across the boundary, to get a local homeomorphism $F: S^n\to S^n$, which has to be a covering map, hence, a homeomorphism (*provided that $n\ge 2$*). From this, conclude that $f$ is bijective, hence, a diffeomorphism. *If $n=1$ then $f$ is strictly monotonic and, hence, is a diffeomorphism.*

From this, conclude that maps $f$ with $J_f>1$ do not exist.

Comment: (For completeness, the $n=1$ case is an easy consequence of the fundamental theorem of calculus.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Right, I forgot about this special case.